# How to filter by year and week in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to calculate a sum of some fields grouped by Week and year , for exemple 
when **dt_extract** is : 02-01-2017 : so the number of the week is 1 and Year 2017 but the problem with my query i don't know exactly is 2017 or 2016  i juste control the week but i need to get the number of the week and also the year to calculate my Sum .

```
var group1 = {

$group :{

        _id:{
                "$isoWeek": "$dt_extract"},

        "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":{
        "$sum":"$mlf16_txfiabnum"   
        }

}
}

var sort ={

$sort : { _id : -1 } 


}
}


 db.mplf_tmp_v3.aggregate([group1,sort])
```

This query it's work but i can't find for which year (in my collection i have 2016, 2017 and soon i will get 2018)

I did this request but i got no result

```
var match = {


$match : {

         "dt_extract": {"$in":
     [
         "2017-01-02",
         "2017-12-04" 
         ]
     }


}


}

var group = {

$group :{
            "_id":{
                "$isoweek" :"$dt_extract" , 

        },

        "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":{
        "$sum":"$mlf16_txfiabnum"   
        }
}
}

 db.supplierswarnings.aggregate([match,group])
```

Here an exemple of the Document for this collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2813a32539c8990f725a8f"),
    "dt_extract" : ISODate("2017-05-14T00:00:00.000+02:00"),
    "mlf16_annee" : "2017",
    "mlf16_semind" : "19",
    "mlf16_semcal" : "19",
    "mlf16_cptmag" : "0000900156",
    "mlf16_codraft" : "02",
    "mlf16_cptfou" : "0000115768",
    "mlf16_codadrdl" : "01",
    "mlf16_codadres" : "01",
    "mlf16_grpges" : "4P",
    "mlf16_clasges" : "2",
    "mlf16_txservnum" : 1,
    "mlf16_txservden" : 13,
    "mlf16_txdocnum" : 0,
    "mlf16_txdocden" : 1,
    "mlf16_txfiabnum" : 0,
    "mlf16_txfiabden" : 0,
    "mlf16_refret2j" : 1,
    "mlf16_refret7j" : 1,
    "mlf16_refret21j" : 0,
    "mlf16_natcouv" : "0",
    "mlf16_nbligndiff" : 0,
    "mlf16_nbrefdiff" : 0,
    "mlf16_cptfou_six" : "115768",
    "dt_year" : 2017
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var match = {


    $match : {

    "dt_extract": {
    "$gte": new Date("2017-01-02"),
    "$lte": new Date("2017-12-04")
  }

}


}


var group = {

$group :{
        "_id":{
                weekNum : {"$isoWeek" :"$dt_extract"} ,
                year :{"$isoWeekYear": "$dt_extract"},
                dt_extract_date: "$dt_extract"
        },

        "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":{
        "$sum":"$mlf16_txfiabnum"   
        }

}
}

var project = {


$project: { 

    "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":1
}


}

var sort = {
    $sort :{_id : -1}
}


 db.mplf_tmp_v3.aggregate([match,group,project,sort])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var project = {
     $project:{  
       correctWeek:{
            $cond:[
                {$lt:[{ $isoWeekYear:"$dt_extract"},{$year:"$dt_extract"}]},
                1,
                {$isoWeek:"$dt_extract"}
            ]
         }
       }
   }



 var group = {

    $group :{
                "_id":"$correctWeek",

            "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":{
            "$sum":"$mlf16_txfiabnum"   
            }
    }
    }

db.supplierswarnings.aggregate([match,project,group])
```

or 
instead of using $isoWeek in your question why not use $week

```
 var group = {

        $group :{
                    "_id":{$week:"$dt_extract"},

                "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":{
                "$sum":"$mlf16_txfiabnum"   
                }
        }
        }
```